# Passing SBCL options to slime?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, slime

How do I increase the stack size in a slime session.

I can do it in the terminal with:

`$> sbcl --control-stack-size 5`

How do I do this in slime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your emacs `init.el` or `.emacs` file you can include program arguments in the settings of `slime-lisp-implementations`. For example:

```
;; Set available Lisp implementations
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((sbcl ("/usr/local/bin/sbcl" "--control-stack-size" "5"))
        (cmucl ("lisp"))
        (ccl ("ccl64"))
        (clisp ("clisp"))))
```

Comment: Thanks! 

I am curious, will the new stack size hold if I create an executable?

Comment: That depends on how you create the executable. You can't use `save-lisp-and-die` from Slime, but you can use it from an SBCL repl. You can use the `:save-runtime-options` key argument which saves `--dynamic-space-size` and `--control-stack-size`. E.g., you could do this from a terminal window: `$ sbcl --control-stack-size 5 --load "my-source-file.lisp" --eval "(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #p\"my-exe\" :toplevel #'main :executable t :save-runtime-options t)" --eval "(quit)"` to create an executable with custom control stack size.

Comment: I appreciate you.